# Is there any way to search the macro name by value?

Tags: c++, c

Thanks to @selbie, a more clear question is

> I've got some magic number or string I need to reference in code. There's a good chance one of the platform header files has already defined this value as an existing macro. And if so, how would I discover the macro with another name, so I don't end up duplicating it was another name?

---

We know that macro can be computed (or replaced in fact?) in compile time. So I want to know if there any way to search macro name by its value?

Here is a example. When I parse the USN record, I find that `FileReferenceNumber` of the root of driver is always `1407374883553285`, so I would like to check whether it is defined in XXX.h previously, then I don't need to define another one.

By the way, if we can search macro, how about constexpr?

Comment: Let's say you are using Microsoft Visual Studio, for example, If you open your project in your IDE and put your cursor on the macro name, and press F12, it will take you to the definition.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I think what you are asking is this:  `I've got some magic number or string I need to reference in code. There's a good chance one of the platform header files has already defined this value as an existing macro. And if so, how would I discover the macro with another name, so I don't end up duplicating it was another name?`  Am I reading that correctly?

Comment: You're unlikely to find it by value.  But in desparation you could do a Find in Files and look for 1407374883553285, which happens to be 0x5000000000005.  But it might be composed with something like `HIGH_FIVE | LOW_FIVE`.  So no...you're unlikely to find it by value.

Comment: @VicaYang don't worry, it happens. I don't think there is a standard way to achieve this, so you'll have to look for specific development environments that allow this kind of 'lookups'

Comment: @Wyck That's what I concerned exactly.. lots of bit magic was used here so I would like to see if there's any tool "compute" it

Comment: @selbie Thankyou! I edit my post to make it more clearly

Comment: I'd bet a reasonable sum of money that NO there's no way to find out if any symbol happens to get defined to the value 0x5000000000005.  That's backwards programming too, by the way.  Incidentally sometimes I do this when I'm searching for HRESULT definitions when I'm trying to look up a text-based description of an HRESULT.  It's hard.  It's easier if you have some context about what you're looking for.  Clues help immensely.

Comment: What are the drawbacks to defining this with your own macro?  I presume there are no drawbacks.  Can you just `#define SOMETHING_MAGICAL 0x5000000000005` and move on?

Comment: @Wyck Yes, there is no drawback in fact. But personally, I prefer to use existing macro so that other developer (with some prior knowledge in this field) will not be confused. Another reason is that I find this is an interesting problem (and probably solvable technically) but seems hard..

Comment: What about something like: `grep '#define *.* *1407374883553285 *' XXX.h`?

Comment: Considering that `#define SMALLEST_PRIME 2` and `#define ONE_PLUS_ONE 2` and `#define MAXIMUM_TERMS_FOR_US_PRESIDENT 2` all expand to 2, you can't look at the preprocessed text and reliably tell which of those macros (if any) was expanded to yield the value 2.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well, usually the programmer knows what the magic number represents (in my example, the FILEREFERENCE of root) so he/she can use the 'correct' macro if all macro with the value printed for he/she.

Answer (score 3):

Gcc and clang will print out a list of `#define`s if you invoke them with the options `-E -dM`. (If you don't use `-E`, `-dM` does something else.)

Unfortunately, macros and arithmetic expressions in the macro replacement texts are not expanded / evaluated, so you'll only be able to find the value if you know it's textual representation. Still, it's a first step.

That won't work for `enum` member values and `constexpr`s. I don't think there is any way to search for those which doesn't involve using some C parsing library to build a symbol table. Such libraries exist, but they're not necessarily well-documented, stable, or easy to use.

Comment: Given the list of macros, one could write a bunch of `printf` statements and run the program with them to see the values (or, more properly but esoterically, use GCC’s inline assembly with immediate operands, then generate assembly code—this has the advantage of not requiring execution on the target platform, so it is more easily made part of a general build system). Although one would want to exclude macros that did not resolve to an integer value.